# Could you transmit electricity wirelessly?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, lightning

Since you can wiggle an electron to get a radio wave And if you 'wiggle' it fast enough you get higher and higher frequency right? So couldn't you just broadcast an electromagnetic beam or whatever and when the wave gets to a reciever it would wiggle the electron and generate electricity? I know it would be unpractical because the waves would dissipate in the air but could you do it?

Comment: hi T.Fisher! What have you found on your own so far? This will help community to focus answering effort

Comment: well, with this question that it would most likely work but I wanted someone with more experience than I do to help me find the answer.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* T. Fisher! I've downvoted your question for the "does not show any research effort" reason. I do see your response to @aaaaaa but, regardless, please take a look at the following link: [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Allow me to draw your attention to: *"Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_cooking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An electromagnetic beam, such as a powerful microwave or laser beam, does not transmit electricity, because electricity involves moving charges. But it transmits *energy*, and that energy can be used to generate electricity.

If we ever put solar-power satellites in orbit in space, they will probably transmit the power to Earth using an electromagnetic beam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one can transmit electricity wirelessly. You can consider the [crystal radio receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio)  as a proof. It is not powered at all, so radiowaves received from an external radio station generate electric current and sound in the receiver. I don't understand why @G.Smith does not think electricity is transmitted in the process. If one uses such logic ("electricity involves moving charges"), then no electricity is transmitted even in ordinary AC circuits with capacitors. There are moving charges in the transmitter, in the receiver, and the air (which has non-zero polarizability).